# How do you redirect to the "base URL" if a web page is not found in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

How do you redirect to `base_url()` if a page is not found that matches the current URI?

I have tried this in `app/Config/Routes.php`, but it's not working:

```
$routes->set404Override(function () {
    return redirect()->to(base_url());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[404 Override](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#override)

> When a page is not found that matches the current URI, the system will
> show a generic 404 view. You can change what happens by specifying an
> action to happen with the `set404Override()` option. The value can be
> either a valid class/method pair, just like you would show in any
> route, or a Closure:

```php
// Would execute the show404 method of the App\Errors class
$routes->set404Override('App\Errors::show404');

// Will display a custom view
$routes->set404Override(function ()
{
    echo view('my_errors/not_found.html');
});
```

---

#### Solution:

So in your case, you could do:

```php
$routes->set404Override('App\Controllers\Home::index'); ✅
```